# Listener for get method in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, listener, elasticsearch

I working on integrating my orm with elastic search. Every time my create, update, delete methods are called I am performing the same operation in my elastic search to update my index. I am doing this by Hibernate listener PostInsert, PostDelete, PostUpdate. Now what I want to know is when my get or find method of my orm is called first I have search in the elastic search for the data and if the data is not found in the elastic search I have to fetch it form my DB. In order to achieve this I need some prelisterner. Is there any type of listener available to do this or is there any other alternative way to do this. Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're implementing full integration between Hibernate ORM and Elasticsearch in the Hibernate team.

See Hibernate Search, and its brand new Elasticsearch integration:

- http://hibernate.org/search/
- http://in.relation.to/2016/05/24/ElasticsearchintegrationReachesBeta1/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the [Hibernate event system](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html#objectstate-events), and implement a pre-load or post-load triger. In your implementation you can access the entity loaded through the event object.

The problem is that these triggers are attached directly to session, and I think there is no way to limit their scope to some entity or query, so in your class you will "see" all entities loaded and you have to choose for which ones you need to overload the search method.

Here an [example](http://dunithd.wordpress.com/2009/10/27/create-database-triggers-like-features-using-hibernate-events/) that may help you.

Good luck!!

Comment: Events are not the solution here as I understand the question. For example event pre select is called every time before select statement and as I understand the question @Muzy doesn't want to do select if he has results in the elastic filter.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply do some middle layer - wrapper for your get/ find methods in which you first check if results are available through elastic search.